How to add Document to existing Chroma Vectorstore in Python Flask endpoint?
I am making a project with a Python Flask backend. Before starting up the Flask server, I can load documents into a vectorstore with no issues.
I am trying to send a file from my React frontend to an API endpoint for it to be added into the vector database. My approach is to make a temporary file directory since the file loaders can only take in file paths.
This is the API endpoint:
documents=[]

for key in request.files:
    file = request.files[key]
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

    
@app.route('/uploadFiles/', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_file():

    # Create a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        file.save(temp_file.name)
        temp_file_path = temp_file.name
        print(temp_file_path)
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            loader = PyPDFLoader(temp_file_path)
            documents.extend(loader.load())
            print(temp_file_path, len(documents))
        elif filename.endswith('.docx') or filename.endswith('.doc'):
            loader = Docx2txtLoader(temp_file_path)
            documents.extend(loader.load())
            print(temp_file_path, len(documents))
        elif filename.endswith('.txt'):
            loader = TextLoader(temp_file_path)
            documents.extend(loader.load())
            print(temp_file_path, len(documents))
        elif filename.endswith('.csv'):
            loader = CSVLoader(temp_file_path)
            documents.extend(loader.load())
            print(temp_file_path, len(documents))
        elif filename.endswith('.pptx') or filename.endswith('.ppt'):
            loader = UnstructuredPowerPointLoader(temp_file_path,mode='elements')
            documents.extend(loader.load())
            print(temp_file_path, len(documents))

        upload_files(documents, vectordb)

    # Delete the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file.name)

return jsonify({
    'response': 'success'
})`

def upload_files(documents, chroma_db):
    print("Begin Loading content from uploaded files...")
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(filter_complex_metadata(documents))

    chroma_db = Chroma.from_documents(texts,
                                     embedding=embedding,
                                     persist_directory=persist_directory)

    chroma_db.persist()

I am running into the following errors:
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2024 11:33:21] "GET /uploadFiles/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:backoff:Backing off send_request(...) for 0.2s (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))
INFO:backoff:Backing off send_request(...) for 1.4s (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))
INFO:backoff:Backing off send_request(...) for 0.5s (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))
ERROR:backoff:Giving up send_request(...) after 4 tries (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))
